# How to overcome kafka.consumer.ConsumerTimeoutException?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I'm using kafka 2.11 version to write a consumer. Im continuously getting timeout exception. Im not sure I use right APIs here

Can anybody help me?

**Executor**

```
import kafka.consumer.Consumer;
import kafka.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import kafka.consumer.KafkaStream;
import kafka.javaapi.consumer.ConsumerConnector;

        public class MessageListener {
            private Properties properties;

            private ConsumerConnector consumerConnector;
            private String topic;
            private ExecutorService executor;

            public MessageListener(String topic) {
                this.topic = topic;

                KafkaConfigurationLoader confLoader = new KafkaConfigurationLoader();
                try {
                    properties = confLoader.loadConsumerConfig();
                    ConsumerConfig consumerConfig = new ConsumerConfig(properties);
                    consumerConnector = Consumer.createJavaConsumerConnector(consumerConfig);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            public void start(File file) {

                Map<String, Integer> topicCountMap = new HashMap<>();
                topicCountMap.put(topic, new Integer(CoreConstants.THREAD_SIZE));

                Map<String, List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>>> consumerMap = consumerConnector
                        .createMessageStreams(topicCountMap);
                List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>> streams = consumerMap.get(topic);
                executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(CoreConstants.THREAD_SIZE);

                for (KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]> stream : streams) {
                    executor.submit(new ListenerThread(stream));

                }
            }


        }
```

**Thread**

```
import kafka.consumer.ConsumerIterator;
import kafka.consumer.ConsumerTimeoutException;
import kafka.consumer.KafkaStream;
import kafka.message.MessageAndMetadata;
public class ListenerThread implements Runnable {
    private KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]> stream;;

    public ListenerThread(KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]> msgStream) {
        this.stream = msgStream;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {

            ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> it = stream.iterator();

            while (it.hasNext()) {
                MessageAndMetadata<byte[], byte[]> messageAndMetadata = it.makeNext();
                String topic = messageAndMetadata.topic();
                byte[] message = messageAndMetadata.message();
                System.out.println("111111111111111111111111111");
                FileProcessor processor = new FileProcessor();
                processor.processFile(topic, message);
            }
} catch (ConsumerTimeoutException cte) {
            System.out.println("Consumer timed out");
        }

        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: 2.11 is actually the scala version which is compatible with that kafka. Probably you are using kafka 0.9.x?

Comment: @nautilus oh..im using 2.11 with java..Is that wrong? What is the latest version for java?

Comment: you can check the kafka versions here http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html

Comment: its ok, if you are using 2.11, what I am saying is that, thats not the version number of kafka.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set `consumer.timeout.ms=-1` if you don't want this exception to be thrown.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11759353)

Comment: the question is How to overcome kafka.consumer.ConsumerTimeoutException? setting that property to -1 is a way of overcoming that.

Comment: @nautilus if we do not provide "consumer.timeout.ms" property, what does that mean?

Comment: @Ratha By default `consumer.timeout.ms` has value of  -1 and a consumer blocks indefinitely if no new message is available for consumption. By setting the value to a positive integer, a timeout exception is thrown to the consumer if no message is available for consumption after the specified timeout value. You can find the configuration information in this [link](http://kafka.apache.org/081/documentation.html#consumerconfigs). Note: Choose your kakfa version appropriately for documentation.

Comment: @JayaAnanthram., so if we set that property to 3 seconds, and after we get that exception, if new messages available will consumer able to poll those new messages?